# Use list of functions with dplyr::summarize_each_

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to apply a list of programatically selected functions to each column of a data frame *using `dplyr`*.  For illustration purposes, here is my list of functions:

```
fun_list <- lapply(iris[-5], function(x) if(var(x) > 0.7) median else mean)
```

I thought this would work:

```
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise_each_(funs_(fun_list), names(iris)[-5])
```

based on `?funs_` which states the arguments should be, among other things:

> A list of functions specified by ... The function itself, mean

But this fails with error:

```
Error in UseMethod("as.lazy") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.lazy' applied to an object of class "function"
```

It seems that `funs_` is actually expecting a list of symbols that correspond to functions defined in the appropriate environment, instead of actual functions.  In my application though I only get the functions, not their symbol names (besides, the functions could well be anonymous).

Is there a way to pass the actual functions to `summarise_each` with `dplyr`?  Note I'm specifically looking for a `dplyr` answer as I know how to solve this problem with other tools.

Comment: In this case `~mean` and `~median` would work. But it is a formula (with environment) not a function. Instead of anonymous function you could use expressions like `~sum(.)/length(.)`.

Comment: @bergant, the main problem is that I don't control the functions, those are provided to me as functions, so I think this has the same limitation as using plain symbols / calls.  Thanks for reminding me about formulas though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `fun_list` is a list of functions, you can convert it to a list of *"lazy objects"* before using it in dplyr functions.

```
library(lazyeval)

fun_list2 <- lapply(fun_list, function(f) lazy(f(.)))
```

or

```
fun_list2 <- lapply(fun_list, function(f) lazy_(quote(f), env = environment()))
```

But I am not sure if this is a 100% waterproof method.

### Update

Based on comments (to have one function per column):

```
dispatch <- lazy_(quote((fun_list[[as.character(substitute(.))]](.))), env = environment())

iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise_each_(funs_(dispatch), names(iris)[-5])
```

The idea is to use `summarise_each_` but not with a list of functions but with a
single *dispatch* function. This function takes a variable, finds the right
function from original fun_list (by its name!) and uses the variable as input.

The solution works if the names of the functions list match
the names of the variables.

It is also possible to define dispatch and function list dynamically (in this case
the environment is not global):

```
get_dispatch <- function(fun_list) {
    return(lazy_(quote((fun_list[[as.character(substitute(.))]](.))), env = environment())) 
}

dispatch <- get_dispatch(lapply(iris[-5], function(x) if(var(x) > 0.7) median else mean))
```

Comment: interesting; one thing I didn't appreciate fully is that `summarize_each` will apply every permutation of function - columns, and not a one to one match.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought it was just a dummy example. So you need more something like mutate_ or transmute_ and provide name-value pairs with values defined by those functions?

Comment: Not quite, I need to apply a different summarizing function to each column _group_.  Note your answer actually addresses my question (well, more like replaces with a different one), so I'll probably accept this later unless someone comes up with something that also addresses the new one...